# Android view behind another with swiping motion

Tags: android, android-listview

to explain the situation :

-i have a listview filled with multiple rows, now i want to take any row and swipe left or right;
either way i need to show another view behind the current row as i swipe( kind of the sliding menu with the action bar, although i dont think i can use that in my case)

when the user swipes left for example the new view can have an offset, (or doesnt), so it may or may not cover the whole row, any suggestions ?
thanks a lot

random code()

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvWatchlists"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_l" >

    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#004c98" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/donnees" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:text="@string/differe"
            android:textColor="@color/title_selected"
            android:textSize="@dimen/footer_text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/maj2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="00/00/00 à 00:00:00"
            android:textColor="@color/title_selected"
            android:textSize="@dimen/footer_text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/maj1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/maj2"
            android:text="@string/maj_le"
            android:textColor="@color/title_selected"
            android:textSize="@dimen/footer_text" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use swipeable list view library from here

https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview

or check this open sourced program for the same feature by roman nurik

https://code.google.com/p/dashclock/source/browse/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/dashclock/ui/SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.java

Comment: thanks for answering, but the swipeable list view library has tons of errors, could you take a look at it

Comment: i had to import another library (noineoldandroids) , thanks a lot dude

Answer (score -1):

It depends what you or doing on by swiping the row view, deleting it or something else

Comment: no i just need to show some views behind the row when i swipe and those views can be manipulated, means they will have textviews ..